# MATLAB - Detect double mouse click on figure

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, video-processing, figure

I'm using `impoly` to allow the user to edit a polygon on a figure. Right now, I'm using `pause()` to detect when user is done, but I'd rather if it were a double-mouse click (similar to what `roipoly` does).

I cannot use `roipoly` though, since it does not allow an initial polygon be plotted, which is necessary.

Any ideas on how to get that?

Comment: Are you trying to invoke some operation after they are done editing? Is a push button saying "done" not good enough?

Comment: No, it's not good enough, as its editing a video frame by frame and I'd like to keep to a minimum the mouse movements or alt+tabbing

Answer (score 2):

The [`impoly`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impoly.html) tool appears to modify the `WindowButtonDownFcn`, `WindowButtonMotionFcn`, `WindowButtonUpFcn`, `WindowKeyPressFcn`, and `WindowKeyReleaseFcn` callbacks of the [figure window](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html). I had originally thought that you couldn't modify any of these because they would be overwritten by the callback function used by `impoly` for its functionality. However, it turns out that they can still be invoked properly. This gives you a few more options:

### Modify `WindowButtonDownFcn`:

To add the ability to detect a double-click, you would have to use the [`WindowButtonDownFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#property_d119e286927) callback. For example:

```
set(gcf, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', @double_click_fcn);
h = impoly();

% Define this function somewhere (nested, local, etc.):
function double_click_fcn(hSource, ~)
  if strcmp(get(hSource, 'SelectionType'), 'open')
    % Advance to next frame
  end
end
```

### Modify `WindowScrollWheelFcn`:

Whenever I create a GUI where I have to scroll through a number of time points/plots/images, I like to use the [`WindowScrollWheelFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#property_d119e287293) callback to advance (scroll up) or rewind (scroll down) the data. You could use it to scroll from frame to frame, displaying whatever polygon has already been drawn (if there is one) or allowing the user to create a new one. For example:

```
set(gcf, 'WindowScrollWheelFcn', @scroll_fcn)
h = impoly();

% Define this function somewhere (nested, local, etc.):
function scroll_fcn(~, eventData)
  if (eventData.VerticalScrollCount < 0)
    % Mouse has been scrolled up; move to next frame
  else
    % Mouse has been scrolled down; move to previous frame
  end
end
```

### Modify `WindowKeyPressFcn`

You could also use the [`WindowKeyPressFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#property_d119e286196) callback to allow you to advance frames using keyboard buttons, like the left and right arrow keys. For example:

```
set(gcf, 'WindowKeyPressFcn', @keypress_fcn)
h = impoly();

% Define this function somewhere (nested, local, etc.):
function keypress_fcn(~, eventData)
  switch eventData.Key
    case 'rightarrow'
      % Right arrow pressed; move to next frame
    case 'leftarrow'
      % Left arrow pressed; move to previous frame
  end
end
```

For more information on creating all these callbacks, [see here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html).

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm still not fully capable of getting it to run, though, perhaps because I'm not familiar with this sort of function defining.
Looking at your button-down function suggested - how do I call it with more parameters? I need that on a double click, the coordinates from the polygon will be saved

Comment: @guyts: It sounds like your needing help with [sharing data among callbacks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html). There are a number of options described in the link, but I think a nested function approach might be best for your specific problem. Without seeing any of your code, there's not much more help I can give than that.